# protoc не создает половину кода

Tags: golang, grpc, google-protobuf

смотрю [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-mHhobE0Pw) по старту в grpc.

Автор генерирует код из файла .proto устаревшей командой с использованием вызова плагина `go_out=plugin:<some path>`. Этот метод у меня не сработал c самого начала, но если не добавлять плагин а просто создать код командой `protoc --go_out=. *.proto` то генерируется файл `adder.pb.go` но без методов для работы сервера и я подозреваю что еще некоторых методов не хватает, а `go_out=plugin:<some path>` у меня не сработал.

Поэтому я стал гуглить и нашел инфу что  `protoc-gen-go` перестал поддерживать плагины и заменен на `protoc-gen-go-grpc`. И в терминале была подсказка что я должен использовать `go-grpc_out` вместо `go_out=plugin:...`, что я и сделал.

Файл сформировался но в нем не хватает львиной доли кода, то  есть файл `adder_grpc.pb.go` создан правильной утилитой `protoc-gen-go-grpc`, но некорректно

Гугление не дало результата и из-за этой проблемы я уже второй день не могу стартануть в grpc и моя задача не решается, что очень неприятно.

Мне необходимо сгенерировать файл `adder_grpc.pb.go` чтобы его содержимое было таким же как в видео.
Сейчас мой файл `adder.proto` идентичен тому что в видео, а вот файл `adder_grpc.pb.go` такой:

```
// Code generated by protoc-gen-go-grpc. DO NOT EDIT.

package pkgpb

import (
    context "context"
    grpc "google.golang.org/grpc"
    codes "google.golang.org/grpc/codes"
    status "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
)

// This is a compile-time assertion to ensure that this generated file
// is compatible with the grpc package it is being compiled against.
// Requires gRPC-Go v1.32.0 or later.
const _ = grpc.SupportPackageIsVersion7

// AdderClient is the client API for Adder service.
//
// For semantics around ctx use and closing/ending streaming RPCs, please refer to https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/?tab=doc#ClientConn.NewStream.
type AdderClient interface {
    Add(ctx context.Context, in *AdRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*AdResponse, error)
}

type adderClient struct {
    cc grpc.ClientConnInterface
}

func NewAdderClient(cc grpc.ClientConnInterface) AdderClient {
    return &adderClient{cc}
}

func (c *adderClient) Add(ctx context.Context, in *AdRequest, opts ...grpc.CallOption) (*AdResponse, error) {
    out := new(AdResponse)
    err := c.cc.Invoke(ctx, "/Adder/Add", in, out, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}

// AdderServer is the server API for Adder service.
// All implementations must embed UnimplementedAdderServer
// for forward compatibility
type AdderServer interface {
    Add(context.Context, *AdRequest) (*AdResponse, error)
    mustEmbedUnimplementedAdderServer()
}

// UnimplementedAdderServer must be embedded to have forward compatible implementations.
type UnimplementedAdderServer struct {
}

func (UnimplementedAdderServer) Add(context.Context, *AdRequest) (*AdResponse, error) {
    return nil, status.Errorf(codes.Unimplemented, "method Add not implemented")
}
func (UnimplementedAdderServer) mustEmbedUnimplementedAdderServer() {}

// UnsafeAdderServer may be embedded to opt out of forward compatibility for this service.
// Use of this interface is not recommended, as added methods to AdderServer will
// result in compilation errors.
type UnsafeAdderServer interface {
    mustEmbedUnimplementedAdderServer()
}

func RegisterAdderServer(s grpc.ServiceRegistrar, srv AdderServer) {
    s.RegisterService(&Adder_ServiceDesc, srv)
}

func _Adder_Add_Handler(srv interface{}, ctx context.Context, dec func(interface{}) error, interceptor grpc.UnaryServerInterceptor) (interface{}, error) {
    in := new(AdRequest)
    if err := dec(in); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if interceptor == nil {
        return srv.(AdderServer).Add(ctx, in)
    }
    info := &grpc.UnaryServerInfo{
        Server:     srv,
        FullMethod: "/Adder/Add",
    }
    handler := func(ctx context.Context, req interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        return srv.(AdderServer).Add(ctx, req.(*AdRequest))
    }
    return interceptor(ctx, in, info, handler)
}

// Adder_ServiceDesc is the grpc.ServiceDesc for Adder service.
// It's only intended for direct use with grpc.RegisterService,
// and not to be introspected or modified (even as a copy)
var Adder_ServiceDesc = grpc.ServiceDesc{
    ServiceName: "Adder",
    HandlerType: (*AdderServer)(nil),
    Methods: []grpc.MethodDesc{
        {
            MethodName: "Add",
            Handler:    _Adder_Add_Handler,
        },
    },
    Streams:  []grpc.StreamDesc{},
    Metadata: "adder.proto",
}
```

При этом все упоминания AdRequest AdResponse помечаются как ошибка ибо структуры не сгенерировались

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?
Неужели нет решения или вопрос непонятный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

решил проблему взяв пример команды генерации с оф [сайта](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/).

Команда на сайте выглядит так:

```
protoc --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative \
    --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative \
    helloworld/helloworld.proto
```

Но я ее адаптировал до вида

```
protoc --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=. *.proto
```

В итоге получил 2 файла: один от `protoc-gen-go`, второй от `protoc-gen-go-grpc`.

Сперва в созданном grpc файле были ошибки в виде недекларированных имен и ошибки импорта пакетов grpc. Решил так:

удалил сгенерированные `.pb.go` файлы, потом в терминале

`cd <путь/к/папке/прокта`

`go mod init <имя_папки_проекта_без_пути_и_слэшей>`

`go mod tidy`

В дереве проекта появятся файлы `go.sum`, `go.mod`
Далее:

`protoc --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=. *.proto`

При этом в .proto файле добавлен ключ

`option go_package = "./pkgpb";`

который создает файлы в указанной папке(у меня это вложенная в папку проекта папка pkgpb)

Буду пробовать пользоваться сгенерированным кодом.

Думаю будет достаточно локальный пакет `pkgpb` импортировать в основной код, чтобы вызывать сгенерированные методы, так как оба сгенерированных файла теперь в одном пакете. Но не проверял пока что

Итог:

`protoc-gen-go-grpc` создал методы для сетевых манипуляций, а `protoc-gen-go` создал все остальные основные методы)))