# ошибка типов в grpc

Tags: golang, grpc

Всем привет
Вот [проблемный проект](https://github.com/udonetsm/grpctest)
В фале cmd/server/main.go возникает ошибка:

`cannot use srv (variable of type adder.GRPCServer) as pkgpb.AdderServer value in argument to pkgpb.RegisterAdderServer: missing method Add (Add has pointer receiver)compilerInvalidIfaceAssign`

Я уже извелся искать почему она возникает и как ее решать.
Вот [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-mHhobE0Pw&t=847s) брал этот пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. У меня в дебиане 10 были подключены репозитории testing, установились непроверенные версии ПО, включая golang, potobuf-compiler и вообще всего софта. ТАк получилось что после обновления до debian 11, в sources.list остались репозитории подписанные для 10го дебиана и apt все время ругался на битые пакеты. Поэтому попытки откатить версии ПО были неудачными из раза в раз. Скачал debian 11 с оф сайта, установил, настроил рабочее окружение и написал код еще раз. Теперь все работает и даже больше, стал работать protoc-gen-go так как он должен работать через плагин grpc, раньше нужно было создавать 2 файла pb.go(но это уже другая [история](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1338960/protoc-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)).

Наверно можно было решить это менее радикальным способом, но не хочется с этим возиться...

НИкому не рекомендую обновляться из репозиторя testing.